# How to concatenate all columns values in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, concatenation

I need a query that returns the values of the columns concatenated and with the single quotes in the strings data types, like an INSERT INTO STATEMENT, taking into account their respective data types.

for example, the table in sql server look like this

```
String  String                  Int
------------------------------------

000001  TUBO BUM 8 X 400 GRS    93,6
000002  TUBO BUM 2 X 50 GRS     10,6
000003  TUBO BUM 5 X 40 GRS     11,6
```

I need the result is the following

```
'000001','TUBO BUM 8 X 400 GRS', 93.6
'000002','TUBO BUM 8 X 50 GRS', 10.6
'000003','TUBO BUM 8 X 40 GRS', 11.6
```

is like an INSERT INTO STATEMENT.

I need to do it **dynamically** for all the columns of the table.

I researched and I saw need to consult sys.columns right ?

Thanks !!!

Comment: What are the column names in your table?

Comment: the names doesn't matter, y need for all the columns of the table, I researched and I saw I need to consult sys.columns...

Comment: So you just want to concatenate all columns in table even when  the column is an auto-incrementing primary key?

Comment: yes, i need to concatenate with single quotes the string columns values, but without quotes the int and float values, like an insert into.

Comment: Will you provide a row id or primary key for which you want the comma-delimited list? So you get the result for the record you specify.

Comment: Your best bet is to use the answer that recommends to use a github project since it would cover all possible cases.  Your requirements are not very clean so its difficult to come up with a query for your special situation.

Comment: yes the store procedure of github is perfect, is what i need, but i need for sql server 2005 too.

Comment: ...you're bulk exporting **all** data.  _Why_?   What do you plan on doing with it later?  SQL Server has [bulk import/export utilities](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175937(v=sql.90).aspx) (which deals with data, not `INSERT` statements, and may be more portable in some cases), like pretty much every RDBMS in existence.  Usually, these will be far more efficient than dealing with millions of individual inserts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/drumsta/sql-generate-insert) is a github project for a solution to autogenerating insert statements for tables.

Comment: Great, happy to help. Please upvote and accept my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

use below script. It generates insert statements.

```
declare @sql varchar(max) = (select STUFF((SELECT ', ' + C.name
            FROM sys.columns C
            WHERE object_id = object_id('MyTable')
            FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, ''))

declare @data varchar(max) = 'SELECT ''INSERT INTO MyTable (xx5xx) VALUES ('' + ''vx5xv'' + CAST(' + @sql + ' as varchar) + ''vx5xv'' + '')'' FROM MyTable'
set @data = replace(@data, ', ',  ' as varchar) + ''vx5xv'' + '', '' + ''vx5xv'' + CAST(')
set @data = replace(replace(@data, 'xx5xx', @sql), 'vx5xv', '''''')
print @data

exec(@data)
```

Answer (score -1):

It is too easy,

```
DECLARE @ISIN NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
SELECT TOP 20 @ISIN += CONCAT(ISIN, ', ') FROM #WBO_TEMP_TBL_CLASS_DATA
SELECT @ISIN
```